# Query Firestore data and add one field to all the documents that match the query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an Android app to sell books. My users can post ads for their used books and sell them. I am planning to add a feature where my users can opt to go anonymous. There will be checkbox with name `Make me anonymous`. If users check that box, their phone number and name will not be visible to others. Only a generic name should be visible.

Now the problem is, I want to put an entry `anonymous = true` in every ad documents that the user uploaded.

I want to query the ads that the user put and add a field `anonymous = true`. I want to do something like below:

```
 final CheckBox anonymousCB = findViewById(R.id.anonymousCB);
    anonymousCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (anonymousCB.isChecked()){
                WriteBatch batch = firestore.batch();
                DocumentReference sfRef = firestore.collection("books").whereEqualTo(uid,uid);
                batch.update(sfRef, "anonymous", "true");
            }
        }
    });
```

But I cannot make a query and insert a field into all the documents that match the query. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please see my answe below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do this?

Yes, there is. To solve this, please use the following lines of code inside `onCheckedChanged()` method:

```
Query sfRef = firestore.collection("books").whereEqualTo(uid, uid);
sfRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getId());
            }

            for (String id : list) {
                firestore.collection("books").document(id).update("anonymous", true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "anonymous field successfully updated!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code would be to add the `anonymous` property to all your `book` objects and set it to `true`. Please note, I have used the boolean `true` and **not** the String true as you have used in your code. Is more convenient to be used in this way.

**P.S.** If you are using a model class for your books, please also see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179367/how-to-update-one-field-from-all-documents-using-pojo-in-firestore)**.

Comment: Hi Karthik! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex, "DocumentReference sfRef = firestore.collection("books").whereEqualTo(uid, uid);" this line is a Query. That cannot be casted to DocumentReference. When I tried this, I am getting "Incompatabe types" error. If I put it like "Query sfRef = firestore.collection("books").whereEqualTo("uid", uid);", its accepting. But this will not work for me.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad, should be `Query` and **not** `DocumentReference`, sorry about that. Just updated my answer. You say is accepting, that's good but why do you say it is not working for you? I have personally tested and it works pretty fine.